# EclipseLink composite key with @EmbeddedId and @Embeddable

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Need your help guys.

I have Table Request and it has one to Many relationship with request notes table.

So we have request table, a join table called request_note table and notes table.

Request table is annotated like this.

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "REQUEST" )
public class Request implements Serializable {

  /**
  Different other columns and below is request note table
  **/
  @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "request" )
  private List<RequestNote> requestNoteList;
}
```

Next I have the join table with both Request id and note id table

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "REQUEST_NOTE" )
public class RequestNote implements Serializable {


  @EmbeddedId
  protected RequestNotePK requestNotePK;
  @ManyToOne( optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
  private Request request;
  @JoinColumn( name = "NOTE", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false )
  @ManyToOne( optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
  private Note note;
  }
```

And now I have the Notes table by itself, which is regular table. which has its own @SequenceGenerator

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "NOTE" )
public class Note implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @NotNull
  @GeneratedValue( generator = "NOTE_SEQ" )
  @SequenceGenerator( name = "NOTE_SEQ", sequenceName = "NOTE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1 )
  private String id;

  @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "note" )
  private List<RequestNote> requestNoteList;

  }
```

Now from user interface, user can change, add or delete notes for a Request.

And when I add new Note from UI, I have the following code. Here I have Request Id already but Notes id has to be generated and saved to Join table (request_note) table and I am getting error.

```
//Create New Note
        Note newNote = new Note();
        newNote = noteFromUI;
        //something like that very common


          //Creating new Request Note row
          RequestNote newRequestNote = new RequestNote();
          newRequestNote.setNote(noteFromUI);
          newRequestNote.setRequest(getRequest());
          RequestNotePK requestNotePK =
                  new RequestNotePK(getRequest().getId(), noteFromUI.getId());
          newRequestNote.setRequestNotePK(requestNotePK);

          getRequest().addRequestNoteList(newRequestNote);
```

The Problem or error I have it now is.

1. It created - INSERT INTO NOTE properly with sequence - Successful - with Id 600
2. Now its trying to run  - INSERT INTO REQUEST_NOTE and since I have request id already there is no issue but the new generated Note id - 600 in this case was not getting assigned to REQUEST_NOTE table.

I guess this is common problem but I am not able to figure out where I am doing wrong.

How do I let my join table Request Note table know that, it has to use newly created id from Note table to its join table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JPA 2.0 you can use derrived IDs, specifically the @MapsId like this:

```
  @MapsId("id")//attribute name from within RequestNotePK 
  @JoinColumn( name = "NOTE", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  @ManyToOne( optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
  private Note note;
```

If not, then you must manually set the id from note into the RequestNotePK  instance.  What is missing from your code is that the ID is only guaranteed to be set when you call flush:

```
  Note newNote = new Note();
  newNote = noteFromUI;
  em.persist(newNote);//ID would be set if the sequence allows a pre allocation
  em.flush();//issues statements and will set sequence values
```

After this, the note.id will be set and can be used in setting the RequestNote.RequestNotePK.id